# Get a list of the most streamed 10000 Soundcloud songs of all time

Tags: python, api, web-scraping, soundcloud

I would like to have a list of most streamed 10000 Soundcloud songs of all time? Each track should include the artist, song name, & the stream count.

I'm currently stuck as I don't know any Soundcloud API that could provide it.

The only way possible I see is scraping all pages of Soundcloud (without getting rate limited or blacklisted) & then creating that list.

Is there a way to do it better than this? If not, how would you approach the problem?

Comment: You need to read this first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Then you need to post your coding efforts, and ask a focused, clear **programming** question. Is there a webpage with most streamed one thousand songs on Soundfcloud? If so, can you provide the url? (in your minimal reproducible example, of course).

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus, thanks for the feedback! I've rewritten my question. There is no webpage for that. Only the 1) weekly top streamed & 2) weekly hottest songs.